# Does scipy.stats produce different random numbers for different computer hardware?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, hardware

I'm having a problem where I'm getting different random numbers across different computers despite

- `scipy.__version__ == '1.2.1'` on all computers
- `numpy.__version__ == '1.15.4'` on all computers
- `random_state` seed is fixed to the same number (42) in every function call that generates random numbers for reproducible results

The code is a bit to complex to post in full here, but I noticed results start to diverge specifically when sampling from a **multivariate normal**:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
seed = 42
n_sim = 1000000
d = corr_mat.shape[0] # corr_mat is a 15x15 correlation matrix, numpy.ndarray
# results diverge from here across different hardware
z = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(d), cov=corr_mat).rvs(n_sim, random_state=seed)
```

`corr_mat` is a correlation matrix (see Appendix below) and is the same across all computers.

The two different computers we are testing on are

#### Computer 1

---

- OS: Windows 7
- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2623 v4 @ 2.60Ghz 2.60 Ghz (2 processors)
- RAM: 64 GB
- System type: 64-bit

---

#### Computer 2

---

- OS: Windows 7
- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) **CPU E5-2660 v3** @ 2.10Ghz 2.10 Ghz (2 processors)
- RAM: 64 GB
- System type: 64-bit

---

#### Appendix

```
corr_mat
>>> array([[1.  , 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.25, 0.25,
        0.25, 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 ],
       [0.15, 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.15, 0.05, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15,
        0.  , 0.15, 0.15, 0.15],
       [0.25, 0.  , 1.  , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2 , 0.  , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ,
        0.25, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 1.  , 0.25, 0.25, 0.2 , 0.  , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ,
        0.25, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.25, 1.  , 0.25, 0.2 , 0.  , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ,
        0.25, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.  , 0.2 , 0.  , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ,
        0.25, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 1.  , 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
        0.2 , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.1 , 0.05, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.15, 1.  , 0.15, 0.15, 0.15,
        0.  , 0.15, 0.15, 0.15],
       [0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.25, 0.15, 1.  , 0.25, 0.25,
        0.2 , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.25, 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.25, 0.15, 0.25, 1.  , 0.25,
        0.2 , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.25, 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.25, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 1.  ,
        0.2 , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2 , 0.  , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ,
        1.  , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.25, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
        0.2 , 1.  , 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.25, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
        0.2 , 0.25, 1.  , 0.25],
       [0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.25, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
        0.2 , 0.25, 0.25, 1.  ]])
```

Comment: Instead of an indirect measure such as correlation, which might have its own platform dependent implementation issues, have you tried dumping your million normals to a file and diff'ing the files from the two platforms?

Comment: yes that's what I did in the first place which lead me to the code above - the diff showed the two sets of normal rv's were different on the two computers. but now I dont know why. the strange thing is, I even created a test for `stats.multivariate_normal` for a smaller size (2x2) corr matt which produces the same results across both computers. the issue may be with the 15x15 corr_mat I have above, but I have checked and it is the same on both computers

Comment: Sampling from a correlated multinormal involves I believe a decomposition of the covariance matrix. I suppose that is a candidate source of the divergence you observe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is an educated guess which I cannot validate since I don't have multiple machines.

Sampling from a correlated multinormal is typically done by sampling from an uncorrelated standard normal and then multiplying with a "square root" of the covariance matrix. I get a fairly similar sample to the one scipy produces with seed set at 42 and your covariance matrix if I use instead `identity(15)` for the covariance and then multiply with `l*sqrt(d)` where `l,d,r = np.linalg.svd(covariance)`

SVD is I suppose complex enough to explain small differences between platforms.

How can this snowball into something significant?

I think your choice of covariance matrix is to blame, since it has nonunique eigenvalues. As a consequence SVD is not unique, since eigenspaces to a given multiple eigenvalue can be rotated. This has the potential to hugely amplify a small numerical difference.

It would be interesting to see whether the differences you see persist if you test with a different covariance matrix with unique eigenvalues.

*Edit*:

For reference, here is what i tried for your smaller (6D) example:

```
>>> cm6 = np.array([[1,.5,.15,.15,0,0], [.5,1,.15,.15,0,0],[.15,.15,1,.25,0,0],[.15,.15,.25,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,.1],[0,0,0,0,.1,1]])
>>> ls6,ds6,rs6 = np.linalg.svd(cm6)
>>> np.random.seed(42)
>>> cs6 = stats.multivariate_normal(cov=cm6).rvs()
>>> np.random.seed(42)
>>> is6 = stats.multivariate_normal(cov=np.identity(6)).rvs()
>>> LS6 = ls6*np.sqrt(ds6)
>>> np.allclose(cs6, LS6@is6)
True
```

As you report that the problem persists with unique eigenvalues here is one more possibility. Above I have used `svd` to compute eigen vectors / values which is ok since cov is symmetric. What happens if we use `eigh` instead?

```
>>> de6,le6 = np.linalg.eigh(cm6)
>>> LE6 = le6*np.sqrt(de6)
>>> cs6
array([-0.00364915, -0.23778611, -0.50111166, -0.7878898 , -0.91913994,
        1.12421904])
>>> LE6@is6
array([ 0.54338614,  1.04010029, -0.71379193, -0.88313042, -0.60813547,
        0.26082989])
```

These are different. Why? First, `eigh` orders the eigenspaces the other way round:

```
>>> ds6
array([1.7 , 1.1 , 1.05, 0.9 , 0.75, 0.5 ])
>>> de6
array([0.5 , 0.75, 0.9 , 1.05, 1.1 , 1.7 ])
```

Does that fix it? Almost.

```
>>> LE6[:, ::-1]@is6
array([-0.00364915, -0.23778611, -0.50111166, -0.7878898 , -1.12421904,
        0.91913994])
```

We see that the last two samples are swapped and their signs flipped. Turns out this is due to the sign of one eigen vector being inverted.

So even for unique eigen values we can get large differences because of ambiguities in (1) the order of eigen spaces and (2) the sign of eigen vectors.

Comment: Very interesting to know that this is an issue and thanks for pointing it out. I thought if the covariance matrix was positive semi-definite it would be sufficient. Although, my issue does still persist even with a covariance matrix with unique eigenvalues (I tried array([[1,.5,.15,.15,0,0], [.5,1,.15,.15,0,0],[.15,.15,1,.25,0,0],[.15,.15,.25,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,.1],[0,0,0,0,.1,1]]) ). I suspect at this point this may be an issue with different versions of MKL / BLAS / LAPACK. Thanks again!

Comment: Great edit. Having played around with my computers a bit more and ensuring the libraries are all the same version, I found the issue **did not persist** using the small 6d matrix with unique eigenvalues. I guess this means the issue must be as you suggested, that SVD is not unique. Great to know that this is a potential issue when testing stochastic models. The last thing I don't understand, is that if SVD is not unique, why did I always get the same results on one computer, but different results across computers - could this definitely not be hardware?

Comment: @PyRsquared : There are multiple reasons for that.   These include parallel operations finishing in a different order, differences among floating-point math implementations (especially where as-accurate-as-possible results are not mandatory to implement), and floating-point operations being carried out in a different order.  Applications should avoid generating "random" floating-point numbers (or at least doing so using complex algorithms) when they desire repeatable "randomness".  See also a [footnote](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Notes) in my related article.

Comment: @PyRsquared re: _"why did I always get the same results on one computer"_ It is perfectly plausible that the implementation is deterministic, so will all things being equal always find the same answer. But as soon as there is a tiny difference somewhere on the way the final result can look very different. I think (but am absolutely no expert on that and may be wrong here) that hardware revisions can indeed introduce tiny changes to floating point arithmetic.